# How to add a link to an image in a view

Tags: views

I have a view that is showing a single image, and I need the image to link to a specific URL, but when I try using Rewrite Results on the field it will still show the image but doesn't add the link.

I have tried both "Rewrite the output of this field" putting in `<a href="http://example.com">[field_file]</a>` and "Output this field as a link" putting http://example.com in the field and neither of those ways worked.

How can I rewrite the field to have the link on the image?

Comment: 'Output this field as a link' should do the trick. What is HTML output of the field if this is enabled?

Comment: @Wtower <div class="content"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://www.example.com/sites/default/files/logo.gif></div> is all it does, but chadpeppers solution worked for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [image url formatter module](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter) to output the path to the image.  Then do like you tried before to Rewrite Results and add the markup.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="[field_file]" /></a>
```

Comment: This is nice, I am curious to why a simple rewrite doesn't help.

Comment: Like @Wtower, I'm also interested to know why Views 'Output this field as a link' doesn't solve your problem. I assume you have cleared the cache when changing the View, or did that happen when you installed the Image URL Formatter module?

Answer (score 0):

1. global $base_path;

get the base path (if you globally declared in settings.php)

2. $profile_pic= !empty($data->_field_data['uid']['entity']->field_profile_pic) ? $data->_field_data['uid']['entity']->field_profile_pic : "";

Get the image field url from $data.

3. $Logo = file_create_url($profile_pic['und'][0]['uri']);

Get the URI of that image value if the image is present store that  URI

$link_path = "path to where the link has to go on clicking the image";
print the image under a link

```
<a href="<?php print $link_path;?>"><img alt="profile picture" src='<?php print $Logo.'?'.time();?>' width="126" height= "173"></a>
```

here the time is to avoid cache problem with image in drupal it will retrive the latest image from the server.

hope this helps

Comment: It would help if you would give your code a context, eg a `view-...tpl.php` perhaps?